# problem saving Entity objects from json string - how to inherit from codeable?

Tags: swift, iphone, core-data, data-persistence

I have fetched a json string from a movie API. Right now I am holding the `JSON` in a `String` object and I want to iterate threw all of the json and create objects to fill an array of them.
The thing is that the objects that I want to create are generated threw `Core Data` and I didn't find any way for an entity to inherite from a super class.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    httpRequest(urlForRequest: base_url) { (data: Data?, error: Error?) in
        if error == nil {
            if let moviesData = data {
                guard let jsonString = String(data: moviesData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else {return}

            }
        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error with no description")
        }
    }

}
```

Now how can I effectively iterate threw this `jsonString` and create a new entity object?

I wanted to copy?

this is my entity:

[image]

Comment: Would you show your `jsonString` or incoming `json` value?

Comment: [{
    {
        "title": "District 9",
        "image": "https://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2.jpg",
        "rating": 8,
        "releaseYear": 2009,
        "genre": ["Action", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller"]
    },
   
    {
        "title": "How to Train Your Dragon",
        "image": "https://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/15.jpg",
        "rating": 8.2,
        "releaseYear": 2010,
        "genre": ["Animation", "Adventure", "Family"]
    }]

Comment: goes on and on with this style

Comment: Do you familiar with `struct` and `Codable`?

Comment: Your json string is not valid json. Here is valid one:         [{ "title": "District 9", "image": "api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2.jpg", "rating": 8, "releaseYear": 2009, "genre": ["Action", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller"] }, { "title": "How to Train Your Dragon", "image": "api.androidhive.info/json/movies/15.jpg", "rating": 8.2, "releaseYear": 2010, "genre": ["Animation", "Adventure", "Family"]}]

Comment: I could not copy it corretly because of size limitation for comments but what I get is corrent

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be creating a data model that conforms to Codable (you cannot inherit from it since it consists of two protocols Encodable and Decodable, not a class). Once you decoded your JSON to an object you can map it to core data any way you want.

```
struct MovieData: Codable {
  var genre: String
  var title: String
  ...
}
```

Pay attention to use the exact same variable names as the keys in the JSON, then it will work like magic. Otherwise you can use the CodingKeys enum to define the keys.

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
case title = "movie_title" // define the coding key: string pairs that don't match the json
case id, rating, genre...// list all keys that match the json
```

}

To decode the json use this

```
JSONDecoder().decode([MovieModel].self, from: data)
```

Where data is the raw data from the response. If you have more complicated structure then break it down, for example if each MovieModel has an attribute that is an array of objects then create a separate struct for those objects (of course conforming to codable) and it should work like a charm. Don't forget that JSONDecoder().decode throws. It is very useful to print the error in the catch clause to debug.

```
catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your struct:

```
struct MyStruct : Codable {
    var title : String
    var image : String
    var rating : Float
    var releaseYear : Int
    var genre : [String]?
}
```

remade your code like one below:

```
   httpRequest(urlForRequest: base_url) { (data: Data?, error: Error?) in
            if error == nil {
                if let moviesData = data {
                    guard let jsonString = String(data: moviesData, encoding: .utf8) else {return}
                    do {
                        guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: moviesData) as? [Any] else {return}
                        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
                        let array = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyStruct].self, from: jsonData) as [MyStruct]
                        print(array)
                        print(array[0])
                        // handle your array with `CoreData` values.
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error with no description")
            }
        }
```

Here is handling your example:

```
    let r = """
    [{ "title": "District 9", "image": "api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2.jpg", "rating": 8, "releaseYear": 2009, "genre": ["Action", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller"] }, { "title": "How to Train Your Dragon", "image": "api.androidhive.info/json/movies/15.jpg", "rating": 8.2, "releaseYear": 2010, "genre": ["Animation", "Adventure", "Family"]}]
    """
    do {
        let data = r.data(using: .utf8)
        guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data ?? Data()) as? [Any] else {return}
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
        let array = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyStruct].self, from: jsonData) as [MyStruct]
        print(array)
        print(array[0])
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: the thing about your solution is that you are not using an cxdatamodelid file - will that struct that you made that conforms to the Codable protocol be able to be saved into and loaded from Core Data?

Comment: I think, there is a couple ways to do it. Try to deep into with conforming `Codable` with `Core Data`:  https://medium.com/@andrea.prearo/working-with-codable-and-core-data-83983e77198e